# Import Angular unit test report into Sonarqube

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, sonarqube, karma-jasmine

**Context**

In an Angular5 project using karma and jasmine for unit testing, I am generating this report file for my unit tests using karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter.

```
<testExecutions version="1">
  <file path="src/app/app.component.spec.ts">
    <testCase name="app/app.component.spec.ts should create the app" duration="314"/>
    <testCase name="app/app.component.spec.ts should have as title 'Projet de test Angular5'" duration="104"/>
    <testCase name="src/app/app.component.spec.ts should render title in a h1 tag" duration="114"/>
  </file>
  <file path="src/app/client-add/client-add.component.spec.ts">
    <testCase name="client-add/client-add.component.spec.ts should create" duration="107"/>
  </file>
  <file path="app/client.service.spec">
    <testCase name="app/client.service.spec #getClients should return an Observable&lt;Client[]>" duration="38"/>
  </file>
  <file path="src/app/message.service">
    <testCase name="app/message.service should be created" duration="35"/>
  </file>
</testExecutions>
```

But when I import it into Sonarqube (v6.7) (via Jenkins), I get the following

```
INFO: Sensor Generic Test Executions Report
WARN: Property 'sonar.genericcoverage.unitTestReportPaths' is deprecated. Please use 'sonar.testExecutionReportPaths' instead.
INFO: Parsing C:\Users\adminpp\.jenkins\workspace\ELIS JustElis Beta WEB\reports\ut_report.xml
INFO: Imported test execution data for 0 files
INFO: Test execution data ignored for 4 unknown files, including:
src/app/app.component.spec.ts
src/app/client-add/client-add.component.spec.ts
src/app/client.service.spec
src/app/message.service
INFO: Sensor Generic Test Executions Report (done) | time=110ms
```

Here are my sonar properties for excluding and including sources and test codes.

```
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=.
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/** 
sonar.test.inclusions = **/*.spec.ts
sonar.import_unkown_files=true
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=reports/ut_report.xml
```

I checked and I have my *.spec.ts files where they are supposed to be.

**Questions**

Why Sonarqube doesn't find my files?

Have I missed a property or an important step?

(Is this property `sonar.test.inclusions = **/*.spec.ts` important?)

Comment: can you try to add property `sonar.tests=.`  (value set to current directory)

Comment: @TiborBlenessy I added this property but I got   `ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution  
ERROR: File .angular-cli.json can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files`   Maybe because I added `sonar.tests=.` AND `sonar.sources=.` which makes Sonar index files twice (one for test and one for source)?

Comment: @TiborBlenessy  My bad, I deleted this property `sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts` since I thought it would not be necessary anymore and that's what gave me an error.  Now that I have these two properties, sonar finds my files.  Do you know how these two are related and why i need both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can you try to add property sonar.tests=. (value set to current directory) – Tibor Blenessy

Adding this property in the sonar config worked for me.

I got an error when I had the property `sonar.tests` set but not `sonar.test.inclusions` though but with the two, everything works fine.